# Get custom k8s resources using python

Tags: python, kubernetes

Python kubernetes client easy get info for base resources of k8s itself like pods or configmaps but is there a way to get info for some existing custom resourses from kubernetes api like a helmreleases of FluxCD using python libraries?

Comment: Would "yes" or "no" be of any help to you? Please provide a clear example of what you're asking about and some code that shows you made an effort, or a clear example of something you are unable to get to work.

Comment: @Grismar, Well , yeah, "yes" or "no" are quite sufficient. If there is such i library i want to know about it if not than not. Official kubernetes library doesn't have this means how i can show you any example? Of course a can show you part of documentation with code that get main k8s api resources but what does it has to do with custom ones?

Comment: I know i could just access kube-api with curl or call kubectl through console using script but it has little to do with python itself

Comment: I think [`CustomObjectsApi`](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/blob/master/kubernetes/docs/CustomObjectsApi.md) is what you need. I'm familiar with the Go SDK for Kubernetes but less so with the Pyhton SDK. I'm deploying a cluster that contains CRs now and will test the Python SDK for enumerating CRs.

Comment: `CustomObjectsApi` works for me to enumerate CRs in a cluster.